# плавная анимация хедера

Tags: jquery, css

При прокрутке вниз хедер плавно уменьшается с 60 пикселей до 40.Но когда возвращаешься в обратное состояние хедер увеличивается но не так  плавно.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
   $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').addClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').addClass("smaller");
    $('.next').addClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').addClass("smaller");
   }
   else{
    $('.menu ').removeClass("sticky");
   $('.blog').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_li').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.next').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').removeClass("smaller");
   }
 });
```

```css
body {
  height:1000px;
}
.menu.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 2;
transition: 0.4s;
}
ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
ul {
    top:0px;
     height:60px;
}
.menu_li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 color: white;
 line-height: 24px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.menu_li.smaller {
 line-height: 15px;
}
.hidden-border {
 display: none;
}
.fullName {
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.fullName.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -3px;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.blog {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 margin-left: -23px;
}
.blog.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -3px;
 font-size: 15px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
/*============================ФАМИЛИЯ============================*/
.surname {
 font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: 500;
}
.surname.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -3px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.hidden-image {
 display: none;
}
/*============================СЛЕДУИШИЙ============================*/
.next {
 font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC" ,sans-serif;
 font-size: 28px;
}
.next.smaller {
 position: relative;
 top: -3px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.menu {
  /*  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;*/
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;*/
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background: #bdc3c7; 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50);
 background: linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7 , #2c3e50); 
}
.menu_right {
 width:90px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 36px;
 float: right;
 font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold" ,sans-serif;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_right.normalize {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 33px;
 top: -8px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:500;
}
.menu_right:hover {
 color: #2F4153;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
     <ul>
      <a href="#"><li class="menu_li"><span class="surname">Bulbasaur </span><span class="next">notes</span></li></a>
      <li class="menu_li"><span class="blog"> Блог </span><span class="fullName">Бульбазавра</span></li>
      <a href="#"><li class="menu_right">Обо мне</li></a>
      <a href="#"> <li class="menu_right">Книги</li></a>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому что у вас `transition: 0.4s;` применяется только к элементам "уменьшенного" хэдера. Следовательно, когда у элементов удаляются класс `.smaller`, то и `transition: 0.4s;` удаляется вместе с ним.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').addClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').addClass("smaller");
    $('.next').addClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').addClass("smaller");
  } else {
    $('.menu ').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_li').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.next').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').removeClass("smaller");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.menu.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
}

.menu_li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.menu_li.smaller {
  line-height: 15px;
}

.hidden-border {
  display: none;
}

.fullName {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.fullName.smaller {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.blog {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: -23px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.blog.smaller {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*============================ФАМИЛИЯ============================*/

.surname {
  font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.surname.smaller {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hidden-image {
  display: none;
}


/*============================СЛЕДУИШИЙ============================*/

.next {
  font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.next.smaller {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  transition: 0.4s;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #bdc3c7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7, #2c3e50);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #bdc3c7, #2c3e50);
}

.menu_right {
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "ArialRoundedMTBold", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_right.normalize {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 33px;
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.menu_right:hover {
  color: #2F4153;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="menu_li"><span class="surname">Bulbasaur </span><span class="next">notes</span></li>
    </a>
    <li class="menu_li"><span class="blog"> Блог </span><span class="fullName">Бульбазавра</span></li>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="menu_right">Обо мне</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="menu_right">Книги</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 Пожалуйста. Если ответ решил вашу проблему, можно отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним

Comment: да решил.Но сразу же невозможно принять ответ там ограничение 5 минут :)